# javascript: how can I split this command line string using spaces but args contain spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

the command line string I am trying to parse is as such:

```
   screenshotz [ 'li[title="about us"] a', 3,2 ] 
div.react-bs-container-body tr > td:nth-child(1)
```

I am expecting the following 3 items in a list:

```
    [`screenshotz`,`['li[title="about us"] a', 3,2]`,
 `div.react-bs tr > td:nth-child(1)`]
```

I am doing a `command.split(/[A-z] /g)`, however, I end up with much more than 3, it takes account into every single space inside the second and last argument.

Essentially I need to allow just about any type of characters, however one clear rule is that a user can submit without the `[ ... ]` characters:

`screenshot div.react-bs-container-body tr > td:nth-child(1)`

which should return `[screenshot, div.react-bs....]`

It always follows this rule, the `[...]` cannot come after the css selectors.

How can I make split a string using the spaces on the "outside" and not inside the individual argument parameter in a command?

So it shouldn't split a space in an argument parameter string. for instance that css has a ton of space but it should all be one arg param.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.... that is your first code snippet again? Two lines of string? It looks like anything but a command line argument...

Comment: PS... did you know that `[id^="foo"]` is also a valid CSS selector? Can you explain a bit the background of what you're building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is causing the string to be split on any alpha characters followed by space. You need to break down the command line string into its components:

1. `screenshot` at the beginning of the string, followed by a space.
2. Optionally, anything contained within square brackets `[...]`
3. Another, optional space, then everything else until the end of the string.

Each of these components, grouped in RegEx, can be represented by:

1. `(screenshot)␠`
2. `(\[.+\])?`
3. `␠?(.+)`

   (screenshot).+?([.+]) ?(.+)

I am assuming the `z` in `screenshotz` is a typo.

Using `split` results in blank results at the start and end of the array, instead, I recommend using `matchAll`:

```
command = `screenshot [ 'li[title="about us"] a', 3,2 ]
div.react-bs-container-body tr > td:nth-child(1)`
Array.from(command.matchAll(/(screenshot) (\[.+\]) ?(.+)/sg))
```

The result is:

```
Array(4)
0: "screenshot [ 'li[title="about us"] a', 3,2 ] ↵div.react-bs-container-body tr > td:nth-child(1)"
1: "screenshot"
2: "[ 'li[title="about us"] a', 3,2 ]"
3: "↵div.react-bs-container-body tr > td:nth-child(1)"
```

Comment: is there an equivalent of matchall in nodejs? I get matchall is not a function when running in nodejs

Comment: On Node, that would be `command.match(/(screenshot) (\[.+\]) ?(.+)/)`